# VueJS - Infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js

Currently I have the following fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/rrathatha/jqsvzgpo/7/
(some bits removed for ease)

When testing I get the following error:

"you may have an infinite update loop in a component render function"

I'm not sure how to resolve the issue as I am new to vue so any help apprecitated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not mutate `previousRating`:

```html
<div v-if="key !== 0 && rating(group[key-1].tags) !== rating(entry.tags)" style="padding-bottom: 23px;"></div>
```